# Can Google Pagespeed Insight results be listed from array of urls using Angular?

Tags: angular

I've been trying to use Angular as a way to list image optimization results from Google Page Speed for each url in an array, but I suspect the controller is configured to overwrite the previous results. Results do not get listed in addition to the previous url results. How can Angular make requests and render results for each url without overwriting the previous results? Please see code below:

```
<section class="container" ng-app="myApp">
<article ng-controller="myCtrl">
<div my-gpsi></div>
</div>
</article>
</section>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
var test=document.getElementById('testaway');
var urlList = ["https://www.mywebsite.com/array1.html","https://www.mywebsite.com/array2.html", "https://www.mywebsite.com/array3.html"];
var urlNew = [];
angular.module('myApp', [])
.factory('gpsiUrl', function gpsiUrl() {
angular.forEach(urlList,function(url){
    this.push("https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v2/runPagespeed?url=" + url + "&key=googlekey")
},urlNew);
return urlNew;
})
.controller('myCtrl',['$scope','gpsiUrl', '$http','$sce','$compile', function($scope,gpsiUrl,$http,$sce,$compile){
        $scope.urllist=gpsiUrl;
        angular.forEach($scope.urllist,function(url){
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(url),
                dataType: 'json',
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                }
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            $scope.pageName = response.data;
            $scope.urlBlocks = response.data.formattedResults.ruleResults.OptimizeImages.urlBlocks;
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            console.log("fail");
        });
    });
}])
.directive('myGpsi', function() {
return {
template: '<div><h1 class="jumbotron">{{ pageName.id }}</h1><div ng-repeat="x in urlBlocks"><div ng-repeat="obj in x.urls"><div ng-repeat="n in obj.result"><div style="word-wrap:break-word;"><table><tr><th ng-repeat="j in n track by $index" style="padding:0 1em;">{{ j.key }}</th></tr><tbody><tr><td ng-repeat="j in n track by $index" style="padding:0 1em;">{{ j.value }}</td></tr></tbody></table></div></div><hr style="width: 100%;height: 1px;background-color: #d3d3d3;display: block;margin: 25px 0;"></div></div></div>'
};
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this to work after rethinking the approach. I removed the Angular foreach method, factory and service. Instead, the ng-repeat will be informed by an array of urls modified by plain JS for loop. The results get appended instead of replacing the data from the previous http request.

```
var siteUrls['https://www.mywebsite.com/array1.html','https://www.mywebsite.com/array2.html','https://www.mywebsite.com/array3.html','https://www.mywebsite.com/array4.html']
var myapp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myapp.controller('myCtrlr', ['$scope','$http',function($scope, $http) {
for(i=0;i<siteUrls.length;i++){
$scope.mySiteUrls=[];
    var newURl="https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v2/runPagespeed?url=" + siteUrls[i] + "&rule=googlekey";
    $http.get(newURl).then(function(response) {
    $scope.mySitePageRaw = response.data;
    $scope.mySitePageImageData = response.data.formattedResults.ruleResults.OptimizeImages.urlBlocks;
    $scope.mySiteUrls.push($scope.mySitePageRaw,$scope.mySitePageImageData);
});
}
}]);
```